# xml select query oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have table like this:

```
Type    Root    Description     hierarchy_level
Event   1       Jump            1
Event   10      Dance           2
Event   2       Cough           1
Event   20      Sneeze          2
Event   21      Spin            2
Event   21      Run             3
Event   21      Walk            4
```

I want the xml result to be:

```
<Event
    <child desc="Jump">
        <grandchild desc="Dance"/>
    </child>  
    <child desc="Cough">
        <grandchild desc="Sneeze"/>
        <grandchild desc="Spin">
            <ggchild desc="Run">
                <gggchild desc="Walk"/>
            </ggchild>
        </grandchild
    </child>  
</Event>
```

this is what i came up with but it's not dynamic

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT
        ("Event",                
            (
                SELECT XMLAGG
                (
                    XMLELEMENT
                    (
                        "CHILD",
                        XMLATTRIBUTES
                        (oc2.description as "desc"),
                        XMLFOREST
                        (
                            oc2.description as "desc"
                        )
                    ) 
                )
                FROM table1 OC2
                WHERE OC2.CASE_CODE_TYPE = OC.CASE_CODE_TYPE 
                    AND OC2.HIERARCHY_LEVEL =2             
            )         
        ) AS "RESULT"
FROM table1 oc
WHERE oc.HIERARCHY_LEVEL = 1 and oc.TYPE = 'Event';
```

as you can see i have to hard code hierarchy_level in order to get the first child. now i don't want to do that for any other level. because if it has 8 then i have to repeat 8 times. So if someone can help pointing me to the right direction to make this dynamic i really appreciate it.
 Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look here, it should get you started: http://allthingsoracle.com/generating-xml-from-sql-and-pl-sql-part-1/

Comment: sorry Donal i just updated the question, hopefully it will help you able to help me. Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between parent and child - is there a primary key column ID and a column PARENT_ID or something to connect the parent and the child? How does Sneeze know it is a child of Cough? If it is to be dynamic, it is difficult to make the tags Grandchild, GGChild, G3Child, G4Child - is that a requirement? Isn't it sufficient that the tags are all named Child but are nested within each other in the hierarchy? And final question: what version of Oracle database is this?

Comment: root column determine that. the root determines by digit length. so 1 is the parent 1, 10 is the first child of 1, 11 is second child of 1. 2 is the second parent with 20 is first child, 21 is second child. now you notice 21 is there three times and so 21 has 2 children base on the hierarchy level. and the child of 21 that has level of 3 has another child which has hierarchy level as 4. hope this helps

Comment: Is this datamodel fixed and unchangeable? Or is this work in progress where you can still change the datamodel? Because this thing with digit length of root and first digits equaling parents digits - I cannot see a easy way to solve your problem using that convoluted datamodel, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    xmltype('<event>'||dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,open_tag ||' desc="'||description||'"'||close_tags)).extract('//text()').getclobval(),1)||'</event>') out_xml
    from
    (
    select e.*
    ,case 
        when tt>hierarchy_level then '>' 
--Oracle 10g
                else '/>'||(select  to_char(dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(xmlelement("e",'</'||case level when 2 then 'grand' else lpad('g',level-1,'g') end||'child>') order by level desc).extract('//text()').getClobVal(),1))  from dual where level>=tt connect by level<hierarchy_level)
--Oracle 11g
--      else '/>'||(select listagg('</'||case level when 2 then 'grand' else lpad('g',level-1,'g') end||'child>') within group(order by level desc) from dual where level>=tt connect by level<hierarchy_level) 
    end close_tags
    from
    (
        select 
                s.*
                ,'<'||case hierarchy_level when 2 then 'grand' else lpad('g',hierarchy_level-1,'g') end||'child' open_tag
                ,lead(hierarchy_level,1,1) over (order by to_char(root),hierarchy_level) tt from table1 s
        order by to_char(root),s.hierarchy_level
    )e
    )
```

This query works on your example.
If result xml is always less than 4000 characters, you can replace xmlagg and dbms_convert with listagg.

Comment: when i run the query, i get an error [Error] Execution (8: 122): ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
and the word winthin group is hilighted.

Comment: I have updated answer with Oracle 10g workaround. Instead of xmlagg you can write your custom string aggregate function http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php